# What is the shutter speed, aperture, and focal length of the Kodak Funsaver disposable camera?

Tags: exposure, kodak, disposable-cameras

I'm looking at the [Kodak FUNSAVER disposable camera](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006HOBU).

Does anyone know what the shutter speed, aperture, and focal length of this camera are? Are they fixed, or do they adjust automatically?

Comment: its amazing to see googling didn't help

Comment: I don't know if you are being sarcastic, but I tried searching for an answer to this before posting and was surprised myself that I couldn't seem to find anything other than ISO speed.

Comment: I literally mean it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disposable cameras usually work in a completely fixed mode of operation (lens focus, aperture and shutter speed). The flash can be turned on or off but power output is fixed . Exposure variations are handled during developing (since nobody expects the absolute highest quality from disposable cameras the effects of pushing or pulling the film go unnoticed).

Fuji disposables use a single element 30mm f/11 lens whilst the ones made by Kodak have a patented 30mm f/10 lens consisting of two aspherical moulded plastic elements. Both manufacturers use a shutter speed of 1/100s and ISO800 film.

Comment: It wasn't just disposables.  Many consumer-oriented, reusable film cameras, going back as far as the original Kodak Brownie and many of the Instamatic and similar point-and-shoot types that followed, were also fixed.  Film has enough exposure latitude that you can get decent results without having to push or pull it.

Comment: Huh.. I would have guessed f/5.6 and 1/60s. But now that I think of it, that would be an odd aperture for such small lens. Nice to know.