# How do disposable cameras work without exposure and focus control?

Tags: exposure, film, focus, camera-controls, disposable-cameras

Before I got into photography, I used to use disposable cameras with ISO 400 film. I've gotten some decent results in various lighting, both inside and outside and at different focus distances. How do they seem to work so well despite having no control over exposure or focus (beyond using flash)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the shutter speed, aperture, and focal length of the Kodak Funsaver disposable camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35720/what-is-the-shutter-speed-aperture-and-focal-length-of-the-kodak-funsaver-disp)

Comment: I don't know if it's really a duplicate, since this question clearly states that everything is fixed. But Matt Grum's answer there does cover this question too.

Comment: With similar wording, I should add — I promise I didn't lift it, but it's very possible I subconsciously remembered Matt's older answer in writing mine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Three things:

1. Film is relatively lenient, and exposure variations are handled in the printing.
2. The lens has a relatively small fixed aperture and focus is set at a reasonable distance to get a lot of depth of field.
3. Finally, prints from these things are usually 4×6, and not subjected to a high degree of scrutiny — we basically expect them to be relatively poor.

Comment: I would say that exposure variations are handled in the printing, rather than the developing. (You could do a snip test to adjust development, but I don't think many people who use disposable cameras are going to do that.)

Comment: @coneslayer You're probably right. In this digital age it all gets lumped together. :)